# ACF Gallery для category отдает пустой массив

Tags: wordpress

Присвоил поля ACF Gallery для Термина таксономии Рубрики и Category(перевод рубрик с помощью Polylang). Заполнил в админке для рубрик фото и в шаблоне category.php вывел поле:

```
<?php
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
?>

<?php $images = get_field('gallery', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
  <div class="swiper-slide" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $image['url']; ?>)"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Галерея работает в русской версии print_r возвращает массиив как надо. На другом языке не выводит - print_r выдает Array ()

```
<?php print_r(get_field('gallery', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id)); ?>
```

Поля типа text или простой image выводит в обоих языках правильно, кто подскажет, это проблема ACF Gallery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 решения данной проблемы:

1. Отключить перевод для медиафайлов в настройках Polylang: Языки > Настройки > Медиафайлы
2. Если не помогло, то наоборот включить перевод для медифайлов и каждый отдельный файл галереи нужно будет перевести через подробные настройки в библиотеке.